# platformUniversalDynamic not found after update to angular 4

Tags: angular, webpack

i updated my project to angular4. but now i get an error in my boot-client file. I think it comes from webpack/HMR, but i dosn't really know. Before the error, i don't know something about this file.

The error: cannot find module angular2-universal.

I searched many days for a bugfix, but i dont find something.

```
import 'angular2-universal-polyfills/browser';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformUniversalDynamic } from 'angular2-universal';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import 'bootstrap';

// Enable either Hot Module Reloading or production mode
if (module['hot']) {
    module['hot'].accept();
    module['hot'].dispose(() => { platform.destroy(); });
} else {
    enableProdMode();
}

// Boot the application, either now or when the DOM content is loaded
const platform = platformUniversalDynamic();
//const bootApplication = () => { platform.bootstrapModule(AppModule); };
if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
    bootApplication();
} else {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', bootApplication);
}
```

Comment: I believe the Angular 2 Universal stuff has gone away in ng 4. [Upgrade Guide](https://github.com/angular/universal/blob/master/UPGRADE-GUIDE.md).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think angular2-universal is no more relevant in Angular4 like Richards said.
Maybe the workaround is to use

```
    import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

    const platform = platformBrowserDynamic();
    platform.bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

BTW that's the initial code when you create a new Angular project from scratch using @angular/cli.

Comment: Thank you, this help me. I never created a project myself. i used a plugin from visual studio 2015.